# I want to simulate a Resource Leak

Tags: linux, process

What are some OS system calls I can utilize to "simulate" and mitigate a process creation leak? For example, A fork bomb is similar to what I want, but a fork bomb increases processes exponentially. Want I want is a system call or an idea for a framework that slowly leaks processes over time so that it may be more easily detectable overtime and is more realistic for real life situations.

Comment: If you spawn child processes and don't reap them then it saves their return state in memory...somewhere.  Or maybe create a slow fork bomb somehow.

Comment: You can leak file descriptors by opening files and never closing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a slow process leak, something like this might be what you're after:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (;;) {
        pid_t pid = fork();  // (1)

        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            return 1;
        }

        if (pid > 0) {      // (2)
            for (;;) {
                sleep(60 * 60);
            }
        }

        // pid == 0 : child   (3) keep looping
        usleep(1000000); // 1 second
    }
}
```

This program repeatedly:

1. Creates a new process
2. If the process was the parent, then it goes into an infinite sleep loop
3. If the process was the child (the new process), then it sleeps for a second and continues with the loop.  That process will repeat the above.

With that, you start with process `A`.  `A` creates `B`, then `A` enters an infinite sleep loop.  `B` continues the loop and creates `C`, then `B` enters an infinite sleep loop.  `C` continues the loop and creates D, then `C` enters an infinite sleep loop, ...  You'll get one new process per second over time.  If the program runs long enough, the `fork()` will eventually fail because of resource exhaustion, leaving all the preceding processes infinitely sleeping.

If you want the leak to proceed faster, then you can decrease the value passed to the `usleep()` function.

Comment: Excellent Suggestion!